# Restrict / cut the data obtained from rest api in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest

I am using an rest api which returns multiple fields data of certain object. An object contains an description field which usually contains more than 2 lines of content(contains html basic tags so i am sanitizing it using ng-bind-html). By calling rest api, i am printing the content of description field in ui using angularjs.

My requirement is to just show the first line from description field content followed by three dots(...)

```
  <li style="text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; width: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
                 <h5><span>Description: </span><span ng-bind-html="record.description" style="font-size:15px;"></span></h5>
   </li>
```

I used `text overflow:ellipsis technique` to cut the lines but the problem is every line is printing with trimmed to `width style size in <li> tag`.

How to cut/ restrict the content to single line??

Answer (score 2):

Try `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.

Comment: i am using an sanitize concept on description field content. Bcz of this, multiple lines from content being displayed and it is trimmed to width size. How to make it display only one line?